# Why jQuery $(document).ready() not firing inside Rails render view after failed validation(s)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, document-ready

I've a Rails app and I run `rails g scaffold friends name`. Inside my **Friend model**, I put this:

```
class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :name
end
```

and this is my **new** and **create** action inside **FriendsController**:

```
  def new
    @friend = Friend.new
  end

...

  def create
    @friend = Friend.new(friend_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @friend.save
        format.html { redirect_to @friend, notice: 'Friend was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @friend }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @friend.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

and this is my **form** partial for friends:

```
<%= form_for(@friend) do |f| %>
  <% if @friend.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@friend.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this friend from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @friend.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    console.log("Hello world!");
  });
</script>
```

As you can see, I've jQuery `$(document).ready()` at bottom of my form which log `Hello world!` when I load the form.

When I submit the form without name, it render again the new template but not calling that jQuery `$(document).ready()`.

Demo:

[image]

How do I trigger jQuery `$(document).ready()` again inside the render new partial when validation(s) failed?

And why this happened?

Comment: Are you using `turbolinks` concept ?

Answer (score 2):

In `Rails4` turbolinks concept will come by default. So `$(document).ready()` will not load properly, so u can follow below options,

```
var ready;
     ready = function() {

        console.log("Hello world!");

        };

        $(document).ready(ready);
        $(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

Or

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function () {
     console.log("Hello world!");
});
```

Or

You can use [jquery.turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) gem to avoid this problem

Or

You can use other `turbolinks` [events](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#events) to solve the problem.

Hope it will solve your problem.